# Alexa Skill searching spreadsheets

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to create an Alexa Skill for our community summercamp. We plan a lot of activities for the kids and hence have a lot of stuff we have to somehow organize. My idea was to create an alexa skill that searches a spreadsheet, where all our stuff + location of the stuff is included, and returns an answer on where to find the thing you are looking for.

An example would look like this:

We ask "Alexa, where are the water guns?"

Alexa searches database

Box1 : Football, tennisball and jerseys

Box2 : Waterguns and pool noodles

Alexa answers "The waterguns are in box 2"

Is there any way to realize this idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using google sheets API. You can store whatever you want on the google sheet online and the Alexa backend can access it and give the response according to the request. I have done similar work before, where we had to read data from google sheets. Will be happy to help.